# LibGDX, отрисовка фона

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Добрый день! Пытаюсь отрисовать фон в проекте, делаю всё как в документации, т.е. отрисовываю в методе render поочерёдно

```
drawStars();
drawPlanet();
```

т.е. сначала должен отрисоваться метод drawStars(), затем drawPlanet(), который будет поверх содержимого drawStars(). Но почему-то всё происходит наоборот drawStars() накладывается поверх.

Код методов

```
private void drawStars() {
        stars.setSize(136, 125);
        stars.setPosition(0, 0);
        stars.draw(batch);
    }`



private void drawPlanet2() {
    batch.draw(planet2, 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 8,
            movPlanet.getWidth(), movPlanet.getHeight());
}
```

В чём может быть проблема? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Вы случайно не разработчик Музыка Космоса? :)

Comment: нет, я делаю другое приложение. Если интересно потом могу прислать ссылку.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен )

Answer (score 1):

у меня этот код работает так, как вы ожидаете; только я заменил `movePlanet` на конкретные зачения:

```
batch.draw(planet2, 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 8, 23, 23);
```

поэтому есть мнение, что `movPlanet.getWidth()` и `movPlanet.getHeight()` возвращают не то, что вы ожидаете; например, какое-то маленькое значание и вы просто не отличаете эту планету от других звезд, когда игра запущена.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас нет возможности проверить, в понедельник отпишусь